# Second functional derivative and its units

Tags: dimensional-analysis, units, variational-calculus, functional-derivatives, functional-determinants

Say I have a functional $I[\phi,g]$ with $\phi(p)$ and $g(p)$ functions from $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$. Also say that this functional obeys the property:

$$\frac{\delta I}{\delta g(p)} = -(g(p))^{-1} I \tag{1}$$

*(It seems multiple people interpreted me writing this as me not understanding functional integration. Of course I know that not every functional obeys this relation, but a functionals $I$ that obeys (1) definitely does exist see the proof at the bottom!)*

Acting with a second functional derivative we would get:

$$\frac{\delta^2 I}{\delta g(p)\delta g(p')} = \left((g(p))^{-1}(g(p'))^{-1} + \delta(p-p') (g(p))^{-2} \right)I \tag{2}$$

Where the first term comes from acting on $I$ and the second term from acting on $(g(p))^{-1}$  (product rule). Only this cannot be correct because we are adding two terms that have different units. ($\delta(p)$ has units $1/p$.) Am I misapplying the product rule? What should I get instead? Note that the mismatch of units happens whenever we act with a functional derivative on the function itself times an exponential of an integral which includes the functional at the same point in its domain.

---

Identity (1) holds for the gaussian field integral $I= \int \mathcal{D} \phi  e^{-\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dp \phi(p) g(p) \phi(-p)}$. I think that to understand the issue with the inaccurate units  the origin of a functional with property (1) is not that relevant, but for those that want to see that such a functional indeed exists I include the derivation of (1) for the gaussian field integral below.

**Derivation:** First we write $I$ as

$$I= \int \mathcal{D} \phi  e^{-\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dp dp' \phi(p) g(p)\delta(p+p') \phi(p')}$$

It is clear that this is the continuum limit of a matrix integral with a symmetric matrix M with $g(p)$ on the anti-diagonal (other entries zero). If we discretize the momentum the eigenvalues are $\pm g(p)$. So we find

$$I=C \prod_i \lambda_i^{-1/2} = C \prod_{p>0} - (g_p)^{-1/2}(g_p)^{-1/2}=C \prod_{p>0} - (g_p)^{-1}$$

We can either take the derivative now immediately if we believe we understand correctly how it works on a product integral or we can act with log to turn the product integral into a regular integral. We then use $\frac{\delta\log(I)}{\delta g(p)}= \frac{1}{I} \frac{\delta I}{ \delta g(p)}$ which gives (1) since $\log(I)= \log(C) -\frac{1}{2} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dp \log(g(p))$. The factor of two comes from acting both at positive and negative $p$ since g(p) is even (if we take a derivative with respect to g(0) there will be an extra factor of $\frac{1}{2}$ in equation (1), but I don't think it is important to focus on this edge case.)

Comment: To those voting to close: Is there anything I can do to improve the question?

Comment: I didn't vote to close, but for the Gaussian integral in your footnote, the functional derivative with respect to $g$ isn't what you write it is. If I made a mistake and you insist it is, show explicitly how you get there.

Comment: @ɪdɪətstrəʊlə, thanks! I will include the derivation.

Comment: @ɪdɪətstrəʊlə, I added the derivation. Do you agree with it? If not could you say what answer you get?

Comment: @user3725600, could you elaborate. Of course they are different. The only two properties that I used are $\frac{\delta g(p)}{\delta g(p')}=\delta(p-p')$ and the product rule:  $\frac{\delta f(g(p)) I }{\delta g(p')}= f(g(p)) \frac{\delta I}{\delta g(p')} + I \frac{\delta f(g(p))}{\delta g(p')}$. Both of which I believe should hold. The second I have not shown or seen shown on the "$+ \epsilon \phi(p)$" level so it could be wrong and the source of the mistake. If someone could find why this relation fails and what it should be I would be very grateful.

Comment: Taking a functional derivative on the Gaussian path integral immediately yields $$\frac{\delta I}{\delta g(q)} = \int \mathrm{D}{\phi}\ \mathrm{e}^{-\int \mathrm{d}p \phi(p)g(p)\phi(-p)}\ \big(-\phi(q)\phi(-q)\big).$$

Comment: @Yes, that equation is also true. It is not incompatible with what I wrote. In this instance it is not useful (in fact it is more useful to go the other way around and compute the RHS of your equation in the manner that I wrote!) (Just because your expression looks different doesn't say mine is wrong. In fact they are equal!)

Comment: I misunderstood the original post, so I removed the comment.

Comment: @Kvothe you're right, I also verified your formula without discretising (which always scares me as there might be terms you miss when you go back to continuum; e.g. in this case the eigenvalues should be $\pm g(p)\, \delta(0)$). You also have a typo, the delta function in the integral should read $\delta(p+p')$. Regardless, the properties of the functional derivative you mention, are valid. (I have no useful resolution of the paradox atm though)

Comment: @ɪdɪətstrəʊlə, sorry for the typo in the delta function. Fixed it. Could you explain what you did without discretizing and why there should be a $\delta(0)$?

Comment: @ɪdɪətstrəʊlə. I think you were actually right to focus on the origin of $I$. I now suspect that $I$ obeying (1) does not exist. If there is an extra $\delta(0)$ there instead this will solve the issue with the unit mismatch. There will be two $\delta(0)$'s in the first term and one $\delta(0)$ and a $\delta(p-p')$ in the second term so the units match.

Comment: The $\delta(0)$ comes up because the elements of the matrix are $g(p)\delta(0)$ on the anti-diagonal, i.e. when $p$ hits $-p'$. Which is why discretising is scary, because Dirac delta becomes Kronecker delta.

Comment: The problem with the units is already present in eq. (1). Normally, the functional derivation 'removes' the dimension of $g(p)$ + the dimension of $p$ from the differentiated function but here you only 'remove' the dimension of $g(p)$

Comment: And without discretising the path integral reads $\det(g(p)\delta(p+q))^{-1/2}$ which you can rewrite as $\exp\mathrm{tr}(-\frac{1}{2}\log(g(p)\delta(p+q)))$ and write the trace as $\int\mathrm{d}p \left\langle p \right\vert \quad \left\vert p \right\rangle$.

Comment: @ɪdɪətstrəʊlə, Thanks! So you are saying that $\int\mathrm{d}p \left\langle p \right\vert \delta(p-p') \left\vert p \right\rangle = \delta(0)$?

Comment: @ɪdɪətstrəʊlə, sorry, I meant $\left\langle p \right\vert \delta(p-p') \left\vert p \right\rangle = \delta(0)$. The integral should still be there.